# What does this mean in shell script: trap "rm -f $pidfile" 0 1 3 15

Tags: shell

I was looking into a script and I found this:

```
trap "rm -f $pidfile" 0 1 3 15
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122779/is-it-necessary-to-specify-traps-other-than-exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This installs a trap handler for exit (0) and signals 1 (`SIGHUP`), 3 (`SIGQUIT`) and 15 (`SIGTERM`) that removes a file presumably storing a process ID.

See `man 3 signal` for details about signals.